# Difference between two input

Tags: javascript, html

i need to know the difference between this two input ?

```
<input type="range" />


<input type="number" />
```

What is the difference ! 
 both of them represent a numeric field ...! 
Is the only difference is how they display in the browser ?

range  = represented using a slider or dial control 
number = a numeric input with stepper arrows

most of tutorial sites said that

> the difference between number and range is the exact value of the
>   number is unimportant with ranges

what does this sentence mean ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

> `<input>` elements of type **`"range"`** let the user specify a numeric value which must be no less than a given value, and no more than another given value. The precise value, however, is not considered important.

So the main difference between `range` and `number` is that `number` is for precise values, whereas `range` is not. The values from `range` are **subjective** whereas the values from `number` are **objective**.

An example where the precise values are **not** important would be if you have a color picker. You have 3 ranges representing the red, green and blue of the color. The precise value is not that important. Your app isn't going to blow up if you choose `156` for green instead of `163`.

Another example would be text size on the page. You could have the user select the size in the range 10pt to 30pt. If the user accidentally selects 17 instead of 18, it doesn't really matter. The text just looks slightly smaller, but they can still read it and it doesn't break the flow of the page.

As for the value received by the server (since you tagged your post with PHP), there is no difference between the two. However the use case for `<input type="range">` is very limited server-side. Almost every time you're asking for a number by the server, you want the precise, exact number, and anything different is going to have consequences. You wouldn't want a range to choose how many items to add to a cart, because accidentally moving the slider a few pixels to one side could have dire unexpected consequences. I would imagine ranges would be more useful for JavaScript, modifying page settings client-side or any subjective user settings, like page appearance.

So if you're using a range, ask yourself what would happen if the value is slightly different. If it will not really matter, you may be able to use range. If it will, go with something else, like `<input type="number">`.

Answer (score 0):

You can type manually the number you want in `number` type. You also get a free check if that input is a number. Also, you can present negative values with `number` type. + you can put placeholder in that box.

With `range`, you get that slider. No placeholder for example and you cannot manually (with keyboard) insert value in it.

Comment: You can have negative numbers in `range` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just answered your own question:

> range = represented using a slider or dial control
>
> number = a numeric input with stepper arrows

The only difference is the way they are shown in the browser. They both return numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Before html5 expand more values in input element, all web developer need to create extension function on javascript to validate the input value. This makes developer work extra.

As you see on today, html5 is not only can presenting text data, but also audio and video. So if you face on audio data mostly you must be need to use input "range" type to declare sound volume. Also when you working on Statistic graph where there are min and max value for its. Thats is the purpose for its.

Than, for number type. You can use it for input exact number on your form, without have to provide any validator function to extract input value